# Duplicate records not allow in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have given Duplication Error that similar to bellow records.

Table Name 'registration'

Colunms

> (1) 'User_id' Given 'Autoincrement' + 'Primary key'
>
> (2) 'Name'

When i insert record

> (1) 1 | test
>
> (2) 2 | test

Error : #1062 - Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'Name'

Can you suggest me.

Thanks.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE registration`  copy that information here. Looks like `Name` is set to be unique.

Comment: Also show insert query.

Comment: seems like your NAME field is set to `Unique`, allowing a value to be saved only once in that field across the table.